# Get Name of Windows.Ui.Xaml.DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, properties, windows-runtime, dependency-properties, winrt-xaml

For a project i need to get the Name of a DependecyProperty, but can't figure out how. It is a Windows 8 project (.NET-Framework 4.5). I need the exact name because I need to export xaml in string form.

It seems that in System.Windows.DependencyProperty you are able to access the Name property of a DependencyProperty, but not in Windows.Ui.Xaml.DependencyProperty (as in my case).

**Example:**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDepPropProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyDepProp", typeof(object), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I need to get "MyDepProp" from MyDepPropProperty.

**Example 2:**
"Width" from Grid.WidthProperty.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to get the Name property.